# PostgreSQL VCL controls

Tags: postgresql, vcl

One of the products I write software for is an accounting type application.  It is written in C++, uses C++ Builder and VCL controls, connects to PostgreSQL database running on Linux.

The PostgreSQL database is currently at version 8.4.x.  We use UTF8 encoding.  Everything works pretty good.

We are running tests of our software against PostgreSQL v9.2.3 with exact same encoding and are finding a problem in which all our text editing inputs are replacing multiple lines with \r\n characters.

So for example, you enter 3 lines of text and hit enter key after each line then save it and read it back, I get one line with the line ending characters removed.  When we fetch the data from the database, we wind up with one line like so: line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n where "\r\n" is displayed instead of getting 0x0A, 0x0D in the stream.

Our application is not Unicode aware.  Borland's AnsiString.  (In the process of migrating this app. to C++ Builder XE).  Does anyone know what might be causing this or offer some things to try to fix this in the current code base while the larger conversion is underway?

I've tried the Borland DBText and DBRichText controls and they both do the same thing.

The other point I should mention is we only tested against new PostgreSQL on the server and are still using a 8.x PostgreSQL client library (psql.lib).  So the client and server version aren't exactly at the same level but I don't suspect this is an issue but any insight certainly welcome.

UPDATE:

Here are some command line results from the two versions of PostgreSQL.

Version 9.2.3
testdb=# select * from notes where oid=5146352;
 docid |  docno   | username |            created            | followup | reminder |  subject  |          comments
-------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------
  3001 | 11579522 | eric     | 2013-02-15 22:38:24.136517+00 | f        | f        | Test Note | line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n

Version 8.4.8
testdb=# select * from notes where oid=16490575;
 docid |  docno   | username |           created            | followup | reminder |   subject    | comments
-------+----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+----------+--------------+----------
  3001 | 11579522 | eric     | 2013-02-18 20:15:23.10943-05 | f        | f        | <> | line1\r
                                                                                                 : line2\r
                                                                                                 : line3\r
                                                                                                 :

Not sure how to format this for SO, but in the 8.4.8 command line output, I have 3 new lines printed on the screen where as the 9.2.3 version concatenates the output.

The insert for both databases is the same client.  So something changed in the way PostgreSQL handles new line characters and I'm wondering if there is a config setting to revert the old behavior or something I can do within my select statement to get the old behavior back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8.4 has [standard_conforming_strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html) set to `off` by default, and 9.2 has it `on` by default.

When it's `off`, in a literal string, `'\n'` means a newline as in the C language, whereas when it's `on`, it means a backslash character followed by the character `n`.

To go back to the 8.4 behavior, you may issue `SET standard_conforming_strings=off` inside your sessions 
or

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdb SET standard_conforming_strings=off;
```

for it to persist and be the default for new connections to this database.

Long term it's recommended to adapt your code to deal with `standard_conforming_strings` to `on` since it's the way forward.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that didn't appear to work.  It looks like that is the right parameter too but, alas, it did not seem to cause any noticeable difference.  Just to be sure, I ran this query:  select length(comments) from notes where docid='3001' and docno='11579522'; and I get a result of 27 which accounts for the '\', 'r', '\', 'n' characters.

Comment: Where these comments inserted after the change? If not that's the reason

Comment: Yes they were. I am testing with a test database.  I made the change to postgresql.conf and restarted the database server (running on Linux).  I deleted the text and re-entered it.  I also have confirmed that the input string is "line1 0x0a 0x0d line2 0x0a 0x0d" and when I read it back I get "line1\r\nline2\r\n" in stead of line1 and line2 each on their own line or encoded with decimals values 10 and 13.

Comment: Another test I did was to insert the same data my app is inserting using psql command prompt.  When I use command prompt with standard_conforming_strings=off, and the run a select, I get the desired behavior.  If I then use my app to go read that record, I get my desired result.  The problem only shows when my app inserts data and I have confirmed my app is embedding the character codes for linefeed (0x0a) and return (0x0d).  The difference is my app is using ZEOS controls (trying to get off of) and they are using an older pqlib client but can't imagine that contributing to this problem.

Comment: Your suggestion was, in fact, dead on!  It solved my problem but for some reason I hadn't noticed it when I replied back earlier.  A recent, unrelated, incident forced me to reboot the database server and after the reboot I gained the old behavior back.  To make sure I wasn't going crazy, I installed PostgreSQL v.9.2.3 onto a brand new Linux server and tested there with standard_conforming_strings=off and it worked there as well.  Using Slackware 14 (64bit).  Other server is Slackware 13.37 (64 bit).  Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like something to do with postgres config variable `standard_conforming_strings`. Before Postgres 9.1, this was turned off by default. Thats why postgres did not treat backslashes literally but interpreted them. But According to SQL standard, backslashes should be treated literally. So, from postgres 9.1, this config variable has been turned on and you see your `\r\n` as literal instead of interpretations.

Although this i not the right approach, to make it work in your case, you need to edit your server's configuration file(postgresql.conf) and turn off this setting(`standard_conforming_strings=on`)

Comment: see my reply to Daniel.  This looks promising but it did not appear to change anything.